# Mockito - Verify if an object in a set called a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, set, mockito

I'm having struggle with the **Mockito** Framework:

I have a `Set` of a specific type and I want to verify if any object in it called a specific method. Here is my code:

```
@Mock
private Set<MyType> myTypes = (Set<MyType>) mock(Set.class);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    TestObject testObject = spy(new TestObject());        

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){        
        MyType mT = mock(MyType.class);
        mT.setName("Name"+i);
        myTypes.add(mT);
    }

    testObject.setMyTypesSet(myTypes);
}

@Test
public void myTypeSet_Test(){

    //call method which calls "getName()" for each element in the set        
    testObject.myTypeSet();

    //HERE IS MY STRUGGLE
    verify(myType, times(3)).getName();
}
```

So the `myTypes` object has a method called `getName()`. I want to test, if the method `getName()` was called 3 times in the method I test. I cannot write `verify(myTypes, times(3)).getName()` because the `Set` does not have a method `getName()`. I hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply invoke the verify on each mocked element of the Set :

```
for (MyType myType : myTypes) {
    verify(myType, times(3))
    .getName();
}
```

But this will not work with the actual code because `myTypes` is defined as a `Mock` :

```
@Mock
private Set<MyType> myTypes = (Set<MyType>) mock(Set.class);
```

And you didn't record any behavior for it.
So you could never iterate on elements added as elements will never be added in the `Set` as you do that :

```
MyType mT = Mockito.mock(MyType.class);
mT.setName("Name" + i);
myTypes.add(mT);
```

In fact `myTypes` has not to be a mock.
Declare it as a plain object :

```
private Set<MyType> myTypes = new HashSet<>();
```

You don't need to spy the object under test either.
You want to verify `invocation of mocks`, not invocations of the object under test.

So you can also replace :

```
TestObject testObject = Mockito.spy(new TestObject());
```

by :

```
TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
```

Note that spying is not a good practice but a workaround. So avoid that as you can and above all as you don't need it !

And it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll try the code and give a review, but seems logic!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mock a `Set` here; having a regular `Set` filled with mocks should be sufficient:

```
private Set<MyType> myTypes = new HashSet<>();
```

and then

```
for(MyType myType : myTypes) {
  verify(myType, times(3)).getName();
}
```

That's assuming you actually call the `getName()` 3 times for **each** set element. If this is not the case, and you're just calling it once for each, it would be `times(1)` instead

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that, but seems legit so far!

Answer (score 1):

To verify that the getName method was called 3 times on each object

```
for(MyType myType : myTypes) {
  verify(myType, times(3)).getName();
}
```

To Verify that the getName method was called 3 times in total, on any of the objects

```
public class MyTypeTest {

  @Mock private Set<MyType> myTypes = new HashSet<>();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception{
    TestObject testObject = spy(new TestObject());

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      MyType mT = Mockito.mock(MyType.class);
      mT.setName("Name"+i);
      myTypes.add(mT);
    }

    testObject.setMyTypesSet(myTypes);
  }

  @Test
  public void myTypeSet_Test(){

    //call method which calls "getName()" for each element in the set
    testObject.myTypeSet();

    int numberOfCalls = 0;
    for(MyType myTypeMock : myTypes) {
      Collection<Invocation> invocations = Mockito.mockingDetails(myTypeMock).getInvocations();
      numberOfCalls += invocations.size();
    }

    assertEquals(3, numberOfCalls)
  }


}

class MyType {
  private String name;
  public void setName(String n) { name = n;}
  public String getName() {return name};
}
```

Comment: I guess it would be enough oto know that it was called 3 times in total. I'll try this and give feedback. Thanks! :)